# Create a list of links to worksheets in excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

*Sample workbook attached*

How do I link to a worksheet that has an @symbol at the beginning e.g. "@Sheet5" in the attached.

```
=HYPERLINK("[Book4.xlsx]@Sheet5!A1","CLICK HERE")
```

I have a list of sheets in column A say and I want to create a way to create links to these worksheets, using a formula, or vba if required.

attached has sheet6 with links to all other sheets, but I am having trouble with the sheet that begins with @.
I also want to be able to do this for a bigger list

[image]

###EDIT1

this is what I had:

```
=HYPERLINK("[Book4.xlsx]@Sheet5!A1","CLICK HERE")
```

this is what you/@scott craner suggested:

```
=HYPERLINK("'[Book4.xlsx]@Sheet5'!A1","CLICK HERE")
```

but it does not work,

but if i use the insert->hyperlink option(not the formula), I can get the link to work to  a @Sheet5 named sheet

WB [attached](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/i4kbmvxn6m05bx58qpdq0/Book4.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=wrt3048h9kfin6zm7plwnz0wf)

Comment: `=HYPERLINK("'[Book4.xlsx]@Sheet5'!A1","CLICK HERE")`

Comment: @ScottCraner tks, that did not work